# Serial isolation with 6N137 opto-coupler

Tags: serial, opto-isolator, 3.3v

I have two Raspberry Pi that I'd like to connect together through a serial interface.

I've spotted the [6N137-L](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Optocouplers-Logic-Output_Lite-On-6N137-L_C92648.html) which can work with 3-5 V input voltage. I can connect it to the 3.3 V or 5 V GPIO pins of my PIs. For what I understand with this optocoupler, the output is LOW when the input is driven HIGH and outputs HIGH when it is driven LOW.

I've also found out some devices that do what I'd like to achieve but I've not managed to get the schematic.

[image]

There is also a project on [HackADay](https://hackaday.io/project/296-bench-power-supply/log/5571-serial-isolation-working) but I've not managed to find the same 6N137 opto used there.

For what I understand, there are many types of 6N137 with various logical gates inside.

An easier but more expensive solution would be to use a [HCPL-7723](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/broadcom-limited/HCPL-7723-000E/1236027) optocoupler. This can operate faster but that's not necessary for my serial speed:

[image]
I'm not totally certain of my schematic.

Could you help me to create a serial isolator using 6N137 and give me the correct reference to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "many types of 6N137"? They might be made by multiple manufacturers, but they all have to function identically, or else they'd have different part numbers. (the xNyyyy naming standard is an industry standard, and though I don't think there's any regulatory body enforcing it anymore, no one would make a new part with a name like that and not have it be compatible with old ones of the same part number.)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking, and not a lot of it makes sense, as it's the **output** of opto that can work with 5V supply, and RPis don't have 5V GPIO as it it would get fried by 5V, it's only 3.3V. First of all, why do you even want an optoisolator between your Raspberries, as you can simply connect them directly. As long as the wiring between them is sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HCPL-7723 only operates from +5V, not +3.3V. Its input will be compatible with the 3.3V logic level from a Pi (according to the HCPL-7723 datasheet, logic high is +2.0V or above), but the output will be a 5V signal which would need scaling to be compatible with the Pi. That's pretty easy to do, but is still an added complication.

A potentially bigger problem is the HCPL-7723's need to be powered from both sides, input *and* output. The cable/path between them will have to contain 6 conductors (2 × ground+power+signal). Using a regular opto-isolator, for which the signal is a simple current loop to power the LED, would only require 4 conductors (2 × ground+signal).

For the 6N137, be careful which manufacturer you use. The datasheets for the [6N137 from Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf), and another from [Everlight](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811091924_Everlight-Elec-6N137S-TA_C16496.pdf), do not specify operation of the output side with a supply of +3.3V. Their power supply must be \$V_{CC}=+5V\$. A third version I found, by [LiteOn](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811092140_Lite-On-6N137-L_C92648.pdf), has an output side that *can* be powered from +3.3V. Be aware, though, that all these devices have open-drain outputs, requiring a resistance \$R_L\$, which must be connected between the opto-isolator output and the +3.3V supply, to produce a signal compatible with the Pis:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIeHaP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [H11L1M by Onsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/h11l3m-d.pdf) will work with any supply voltage between +3V and +15V, but is only rated for 1Mbps (the 6N137, by comparison, can handle data at ten times that rate). It will be fine for serial communications at or under 1Mbps.

Another important consideration will be the current needed from the Pi's IO pins to drive the opto-isolator LEDs. For the H11L1M that's only 1.6mA, but the 6N137 requires *at least* 5mA. 5mA isn't a lot, and any Arduino would have no problem with that, but the Raspberry Pi has notoriously weak GPIO outputs, able to source only 3mA or so. Obviously, if you wish to use the 6N137, you'll need extra hardware to take on the task of sourcing LED current. Again, that's not difficult, just annoying.

My recommendation is this: use an opto-isolator that can operate from 3.3V, requires under 3mA LED (input) current, and handles data at 1Mbps or more. Such as the [H11L1M](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/h11l3m-d.pdf). That way, your circuit could be as simple as this (one half only):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjWibF.png)</sup>

With R2=1kΩ, LED current will be about 2mA, not too much for the Pi, easily enough for the opto-isolatior to register a "high".

Comment: Awesome answer ! Thank you very much !

Comment: If I do it that way, could you confirm it will work two way ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/brovp.png [Edited by a moderator to use Stack Exchange imgur hosting instead of public (temporary!) imgur hosting.]

Comment: @Manitoba I cannot promise it would work, because I don't have all the information you have. For instance, I have no idea about the distance between your Pis and the wiring between them. I don't know whether you are bit-banging or using UARTs in the Pis, and I have no idea about your software skills. There are many variables. Also, I didn't build this design, and I haven't tested it. I am *always* surprised by something, there's always something I overlooked. All I can say is that your schematic looks good, I consider it to be a solid design, and I don't see any glaring problems on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Are your two RPi's on the same power and ground systems? If so no isolation is likely needed.

If different grounding systems between the two RPi's then you will need isolation. If you use isolators that end up inverting the RX and TX signals logically then you will have to revert that inversion before connecting to the second RPi for the serial signalling to work.

Coupler devices such as the HCPL-7723 and similar devices in that same part family are far superior of serial isolation in that they are non-inverting and easily allow connecting the CMOS type I/Os from MCUs. This particular device does need to be operated at 5 volts on the supply lead but the CMOS inputs will still work properly with I/Os that swing between 3.3V rails. The outputs of these couplers will swing 5V logic levels and so it may be required to use a resistor voltage divider on the outputs at the inputs to the MCU (unless you can be assured that the I/O's of the MCU are "5V Tolerant".

Comment: I got these confused with the 4N35's and slightly better 6N135's. Always used the HCPL fully buffered units with great success.